# Select INTs from start of string separated by a character (pipe). Update other columns using these INTs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, string-manipulation, string-splitting

[image]

In the above screen shot, the *Description* column has many special characters. We want before | number update in T1 column and | after number in T2 column. Please suggest the proper syntax.

If there are no before and after | numbers, like the second row `| SE +17.5D CYL1.25` update columns T1 and T2 null.

Answer (score 3):

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T
(
    [Description] varchar(8000) NOT NULL,
    T1 integer NULL,
    T2 integer NULL
);
```

and data:

```
INSERT dbo.T
    ([Description])
VALUES
    ('| 30 | 30 | INTERNAL AUDIT | RL | OK'),
    ('| SE+17.5D  CYL 1.25'),
    ('| 10 | 11 | INTERNAL AUDIT | MM | CORRECTED'),
    ('| 5 | 5 | INTERNAL AUDIT | JY | GOOD'),
    ('| 56 | 56 | INTERNAL AUDIT | JMS | OK'),
    ('| 10 | 10 | INTERNAL AUDIT | CN | None'),
    ('| 3 | 3 | INTERNAL AUDIT | MG | GOOD'),
    ('| 46 | 47 | INTERNAL AUDIT | AB | None'),
    ('| 23 | 23 | INTERNAL AUDIT | BA | OK'),
    ('| 30 | 30 | INTERNAL AUDIT | RL | OK'),
    ('| 25 | 29 | INTERNAL AUDIT | KV | CORRECTED'),
    ('| 4 | 3 | INTERNAL AUDIT | KV | PULLING, LIVE AR'),
    ('| ref # - 0006-4121-02');
```

#### Solution

The following commented code uses an updatable cursor:

```
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;
SET STATISTICS XML OFF;

DECLARE 
    @Description varchar(8000),
    @Pipe1Position integer,
    @Pipe2Position integer,
    @T1 integer,
    @T2 integer;

DECLARE DataCursor CURSOR LOCAL
    SCROLL DYNAMIC SCROLL_LOCKS
FOR SELECT [Description] FROM dbo.T
FOR UPDATE OF T1, T2;

OPEN DataCursor;

-- Get the first row
FETCH FIRST FROM DataCursor INTO @Description;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Reset
    SET @T1 = NULL;
    SET @T2 = NULL;

    -- Find the pipe after the first one
    SET @Pipe1Position = CHARINDEX('|', @Description, 2);

    IF @Pipe1Position > 0
    BEGIN TRY
        -- Extract the first integer
        SET @T1 = CONVERT(integer, 
            SUBSTRING(@Description, 2, @Pipe1Position - 2));

        -- Find the the next pipe
        SET @Pipe2Position = CHARINDEX('|', @Description, @Pipe1Position + 1);

        IF @Pipe2Position > 0
        BEGIN
            -- Extract the second integer
            SET @T2 = CONVERT(integer, 
                SUBSTRING(@Description, @Pipe1Position + 1, @Pipe2Position - @Pipe1Position - 1));            
        END;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH;

    -- Perform the update for this row
    UPDATE dbo.T
    SET T1 = @T1, T2 = @T2
    WHERE CURRENT OF DataCursor;

    -- Next row
    FETCH NEXT FROM DataCursor INTO @Description;
END;

CLOSE DataCursor; 
DEALLOCATE DataCursor;
```

The final state of the table is:

| Description | T1 | T2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| | 30 | 30 | INTERNAL AUDIT | RL | OK | 30 | 30 |
| | SE+17.5D CYL 1.25 | NULL | NULL |
| | 10 | 11 | INTERNAL AUDIT | MM | CORRECTED | 10 | 11 |
| | 5 | 5 | INTERNAL AUDIT | JY | GOOD | 5 | 5 |
| | 56 | 56 | INTERNAL AUDIT | JMS | OK | 56 | 56 |
| | 10 | 10 | INTERNAL AUDIT | CN | None | 10 | 10 |
| | 3 | 3 | INTERNAL AUDIT | MG | GOOD | 3 | 3 |
| | 46 | 47 | INTERNAL AUDIT | AB | None | 46 | 47 |
| | 23 | 23 | INTERNAL AUDIT | BA | OK | 23 | 23 |
| | 30 | 30 | INTERNAL AUDIT | RL | OK | 30 | 30 |
| | 25 | 29 | INTERNAL AUDIT | KV | CORRECTED | 25 | 29 |
| | 4 | 3 | INTERNAL AUDIT | KV | PULLING, LIVE AR | 4 | 3 |
| | ref # - 0006-4121-02 | NULL | NULL |

#### Online demo

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8425325a6e3940eaabb5f69f8004c5b5

#### Commentary

The database is not the best place to this kind of work. The pipe-delimited data looks as if it originated in an external system, and was imported from a flat file.

Instead of importing the data as-is then processing inside SQL Server, it would be better to use a dedicated ETL tool like SSIS to *transform* the flat-file data directly then *load* into one or more relational database tables.

A cursor won't be ideal if you have tens of millions of rows to process in a hurry, but it does make showing the logic used clear. It performs pretty well all things considered.

You should also look into getting onto a more modern version of SQL Server. Things like `STRING_SPLIT` and `TRY_CONVERT` make coding this sort of thing a lot easier.

Comment: | Multiplied by 3 | 50 | 50 | TEAM LEAD AUDIT | AB | OK
| KH EXTERNAL AUDITOR VERIFIED | 48 | 48 | INTERNAL AUDIT | MM | OK
this position also get the result  like  :-  50|50
                                                                48|48
i this use PATINDEX.

Comment: @karthiksanapala That's why it is important to supply data and expected results in your question. I hope you learned something about that for next time.